# Error:Call to a member function all() on array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image: the result of the data array, I use dd($cross_kehadiran );]

my code from folder in App\Reports\ExportReport.php

```
class ReportExport implements FromCollection
{
 $cross_kehadiran[] = DB::table('attendance as in')
                        ->where('in.in_out', 'in')
                        ->where('in.attendance_location_id', $locations->id)
                        ->where('in.company_id', '!=', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                        ->whereDate('in.created', Carbon::today())
                        ->leftJoin('attendance as out', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('in.employee_id', 'out.employee_id')
                                ->where('out.in_out', 'out')
                                ->where('out.attendance_location_id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                                ->whereDate('out.created', Carbon::today());
                        })
                        ->join('employee', 'employee.id', 'in.employee_id')
                        ->join('location_library', 'location_library.id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                        ->join('company as cp', 'cp.id', 'in.company_id')
                        ->join('employee_in_app as e_app', 'e_app.employee_id', 'in.employee_id')
                        ->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(in.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as in_time'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(out.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as out_time'), 'e_app.note')
                        ->orderBy('in.attendance_time', 'DESC')
                        ->get();

     return $cross_kehadiran;

}
```

I made export excel in laravel, when i return using dd($cross_kehadiran) the data i want appears but when i use return $cross_kehadiran i get error : Call to a member function all() on array in.
How to solve my problem, help me, thanks.

Comment: because the $cross_kehadiran function is inside the foreach

Answer (score 1):

> import this class at the tope
> use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

> Put all of your code in the collection method according to Maatwebsite\Excel package.

```
public function collection()
          {
                 return DB::table('attendance as in')
                                ->where('in.in_out', 'in')
                                ->where('in.attendance_location_id', $locations->id)
                                ->where('in.company_id', '!=', \Session::get('selected_company'))
                                ->whereDate('in.created', Carbon::today())
                                ->leftJoin('attendance as out', function ($join) {
                                    $join->on('in.employee_id', 'out.employee_id')
                                        ->where('out.in_out', 'out')
                                        ->where('out.attendance_location_id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                                        ->whereDate('out.created', Carbon::today());
                                })
                                ->join('employee', 'employee.id', 'in.employee_id')
                                ->join('location_library', 'location_library.id', 'in.attendance_location_id')
                                ->join('company as cp', 'cp.id', 'in.company_id')
                                ->join('employee_in_app as e_app', 'e_app.employee_id', 'in.employee_id')
                                ->select('employee.name', 'cp.alias', 'in.employee_id','location_library.location_name',  DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(in.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as in_time'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(out.attendance_time, "%H:%i:%s") as out_time'), 'e_app.note')
                                ->orderBy('in.attendance_time', 'DESC')
                                ->get();
           }
```

Comment: I have added the collection function but it still doesn't work

Comment: try this with  collection function, store query in $cross_kehadiran[] and then return collect($cross_kehadiran);

Comment: I've tried that method, but I get an error "Error:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: please reply if it still not working...

Comment: I think it's because when you return dd($cross_kehadiran) the result is an array and then a new array of objects contains data. If the result is in an array, the new object can use return $cross_kehadiran.

Comment: until now still can't

Comment: I still research I found fromquery  to chunk join record  read this documentation on https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html#from-query

Comment: instead of using collection use fromquery and instead of get() use query() in query function  body .and first of all import this

Comment: i will try again, thank you for your help

Comment: thanks, can you vote for me?

Answer (score 0):

you should return like this

```
return collect($cross_kehadiran);
```

Comment: I've tried that method, but I get an error "Error:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"